# Multiple waypoints in leaflet js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

This is my code to create multiple waypoints.
I have an array with 'n' number of lattitude and longitude i want the route based on that lat,long.I don't want to use any hardcore data's in waypoints.
In waypoints array i want to use dynamic lattitude and longitude,how to use this?

```
    var data = [

    {
        "title": 'Chennai',
        "lat": '13.0827',
        "lng": '80.2707',
        "description": '',
        "flag":'1'
    }
  ,
  {
    "title": 'Ramapuram',
    "lat": '13.0317',
    "lng": '80.1817',
    "description": ''

  }
  ,
    {
        "title": 'Kanchipuram',
        "lat": '12.8342',
        "lng": '79.7036',
        "description": '',
        "flag":'1'
    },

  ];
var map = L.map('map');

  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);

var routeControl = L.Routing.control({

}).addTo(map);
routeControl.setWaypoints(data);
```

Here i have attached the image and this is my output,and also my expectation is i want to remove the center marker.i want to set the marker where i want.
 [image]

Can anyone help me out?Now i have updated my code that i removed waypoints and i set the waypoints using setwaypoints function.Now i wantto remove the markers.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're asking. Do you want the user to be able to add a waypoint to the route dynamically? That's covered in the excellent docs at http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/interaction/.

Comment: I updated my question @peeebeee.i don't want user to add waypoint.waypoint is constant.

Comment: Hmm... OK, well the `waypoints` option on the `L.Routing.control` expects an array of `L.Routing.Waypoint` or `L.LatLng` - you can construct that array any way you like. Doesn't have to be hard-coded.

Comment: I updated my question,what mistake i'm doing?@peeebeee

Comment: Do you want to have the route without markers for waypoints? Is this that you want?

Comment: I Want the marker for only source and destination,not for all waypoints.@kiks73

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to draw a route along some waypoints and show markers only for start and end points. Also you want to prevent users from adding new waypoints. Create control like that:

```
L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: yourWaypoints,
  plan: L.Routing.plan(yourWaypoints, {
    createMarker: function(i, wp, n) {
      if (i == 0 || i == n - 1) {
        return L.marker(wp.latlng, {
          draggable: false // prevent users from changing waypoint position
        });
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  addWaypoints: false // prevent users from adding new waypoints
});
```